# Wordpress RTL support editing

Tags: wordpress

using wordpress 4.9.5:

I installed theme which is support (rtl) and it works good , but  I faced 3 problems :

1. My language is Arabic (rtl) but the post box content is (ltr) ,how do I edit it to (rtl)?

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eALqTiKfoFNVWF66BWEgMt-1l6T7NMz8/view?usp=sharing

2. At the post page ,I need to do margin between icons and text ?
   note: when the page is (ltr) there is margin, but when the page is (rtl) there is no margin.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1WZFJCPyYriz7in0SDZWYJowIfZLspb3g/view?usp=sharing

3. At the post page the comment description is in correct direction (rtl) but in english language. How do I edit these text to Arabic language.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1G6xBiAgifnOiKcJbY3Ao4A4Mge8Dv01E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Please only ask one question at a time.  This is 3 questions.  (SO guidelines specifically state ask only one question at a time)

Comment: Also - sounds like your theme doesn't _properly_ support RTL.  Have you checked out any plugins?

Comment: Lastly, this site is for Programmers.  Do you have a programming question? If not, consider asking this on wordpress.stackexchange.com